# No flash player plugin for android jelly bean

Tags: android, flash

Recently I heared that Android's latest Jelly Bean release does not allow the flash player plugin(ie all plugins).But Adobe says that AIR is still Alive and they are saying to consider AIR instead of flash.
After this news, there are so many questions that have been popping into my mind.

1. As far i know even Air is running on the flash player plugin, please correct me if I am wrong.
2. If Air application can run on both Andriod and IOS, then obviously the flash player plugin should run on Android.

I am curious about the technology, so please explain what it is.

Comment: [Jelly Bean](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the latest announcement,

http://www.redmondpie.com/its-finally-over-adobe-pulls-flash-support-in-android-4.1-jelly-bean-plans-to-withdraw-app-from-play-store/

http://www.zdnet.com/adobe-wont-support-flash-on-jelly-bean-1339340588/

they say no more Flash or Adobe AIR on Android.

Answer (score 3):

Flash player and Adobe Air are two completely different things.

Flash player is a plugin just for the native browser.

Whereas Adobe Air is used to develop Native applications
Adobe air provides a framework to write Android apps which you can publish through Google play.

Adobe has stopped support only for flash player plugin not the Adobe Air. This should be a problem only to website developers